# XSLT transform big xml file with less memory

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a Problem with XSLT Transforming a big Dataset(60 GB/ 50000 Cylinder on host).
The Program run's on Mainframe, so i don't get the 2 GB Headsize he need's.
But I don't unterstand why he need so much space, maybe there is a way to do the transform with less space? I don't know anything about XSLT, I needed half of and Day to do this^^

My Problem:
In the XML are many XML-Tags i don't need(in Example person_id, Iso_laender_code), i want to filter so i only get those who I Need.

My XML:
I have many Tags of Person's:

```
<ndm_message><message>
    <Person>...</Person>
    <Person>...</Person>
    <Person>...</Person>...
```

Each Person has Tags like Name, Adress... and much tags I don't need

```
<Person>
        <person_id>24</person_id>
        <name>Person's Name</name>
        </titel>
        <Adresse>
              <strasse>Irgendwo</strasse>
              <iso_laender_code>004</iso_laender_code>
        </Adresse>
</Person
```

My XSLT:
I defined a Whitelist and check for-each Person any Node against the White list:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsi:WhiteList>
    <name>Person</name>
    <name>name</name>
    <name>Adresse</name>
    <name>strasse</name>
 </xsi:WhiteList>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <ndm_message>
    <xsl:for-each select="ndm_message/message/Person">

            <xsl:call-template name="filter" >
                <xsl:with-param name="Knoten" select="."/>
            </xsl:call-template>

    </xsl:for-each>
    </ndm_message>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="filter">
    <xsl:param name="Knoten" />
    <xsl:if test="$Knoten[name()=document('')/*/xsi:WhiteList/*]">

    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:if test="not(child::*)">
        <xsl:value-of select="$Knoten"/>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:for-each select="$Knoten/*">
        <xsl:call-template name="filter" >
            <xsl:with-param name="Knoten" select="."/>
        </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <!--  -->
    </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

I run the XSLT in Java with saxon9.jar.

```
    public static void simpleTransform(String sourcePath, String xsltPath,
                                   String resultDir) {
    System.setProperty("javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory",
            "net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl");
    TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    try {
        Transformer transformer =
            tFactory.newTransformer(new StreamSource(new File(xsltPath)));

        transformer.transform(new StreamSource(new File(sourcePath)),
                              new StreamResult(new File(resultDir)));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Does anybody know why he need so much space? I think the XSLT only reference on one Person and the tags recursive, one /Person is about 32 KB.
Maybe the Problem is the StreamSource and Result?
Is there a other way to do this with XSLT and less space?

Thanks very Much
Florian

Comment: Saxon 9 EE might allow you to run an XSLT 3.0 stylesheet using streaming where the XSLT processor, contrary to the normal XSLT processing model of building a tree of the complete XML input, streams through the input in a forwards only mode. However that requires a license for Saxon EE and rewriting the XSLT to allow that kind of processing.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an XSLT 3.0 stylesheet you could use with Saxon 9 EE to do [streaming processing](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#streaming-concepts) of your input:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs math"
    version="3.0">

    <xsl:param name="STREAMABLE" static="yes" as="xs:boolean" select="true()"/>

    <xsl:mode _streamable="{$STREAMABLE}" on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:param name="white-list">
        <name>Person</name>
        <name>name</name>
        <name>Adresse</name>
        <name>strasse</name>
    </xsl:param>

    <xsl:template match="ndm_message">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="message/Person"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Person//*[not(local-name() = $white-list/name)]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It transforms the input sample

```
<ndm_message>
    <message>
        <Person>
            <person_id>24</person_id>
            <name>Person 24</name>
            <titel>Ein Titel</titel>
            <Adresse>
                <strasse>Strasse 24</strasse>
                <iso_laender_code>004</iso_laender_code>
            </Adresse>
        </Person>
        <Person>
            <person_id>25</person_id>
            <name>Person 25</name>
            <titel>Ein Titel</titel>
            <Adresse>
                <strasse>Strasse 25</strasse>
                <iso_laender_code>004</iso_laender_code>
            </Adresse>
        </Person>
    </message>
</ndm_message>
```

into the output sample

```
<ndm_message>
   <Person>
      <name>Person 24</name>
      <Adresse>
         <strasse>Strasse 24</strasse>
      </Adresse>
   </Person>
   <Person>
      <name>Person 25</name>
      <Adresse>
         <strasse>Strasse 25</strasse>
      </Adresse>
   </Person>
</ndm_message>
```

As for running it with Java, I think to use XSLT 3.0 and streaming it is better (or even necessary, see https://saxonica.plan.io/issues/3120) to use the Saxon specific API http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/using-xsl/embedding/s9api-transformation.html instead of JAXP.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your Solutions, but XSLT Streaming sound's difficult, i usually programming COBOL^^
I decided to write a Java Programm with Stax-parser, and check the XML-Tag's against the "whitelist" in a File. This was easyer for me and I can read in UTF-8 and write in EBCDIC, so i saved an encoding-converting Step in my JCL :-)
But thanks very much für your help.